# "Can't read swagger JSON from http://localhost:52056/undefined"?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

Swagger was working well for me in my Web API 2.2 app at the following url: http://localhost:52056/swagger. However, I recently updated the solution to support versioning so the solution now supports api/v1/ and an api/v2/.  Now the Swagger url that I was using returns the following error when the Swagger page loads:

> Can't read swagger JSON from http://localhost:52056/undefined

How should I update SwaggerConfig.cs to support Swagger for the different API versions?  Here's my current SwaggerConfig.cs:

```
using System.Web.Http;
using WebActivatorEx;
using Janus.SecurityApi.Api;
using Swashbuckle.Application;
using System.Configuration;

[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SwaggerConfig), "Register")]

namespace SecurityApi.Api
{
    public class SwaggerConfig
    {
        public static void Register()
        {
            var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                .EnableSwagger(c =>
                {
                    c.RootUrl(req => GetRootUrlFromAppConfig());
                    c.Schemes(new[] { GetSchemeFromAppConfig() });
                    c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "Security API");
                    c.IncludeXmlComments(
                        string.Format(
                            @"{0}\App_Data\SecurityApi.Api.xml",
                            System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory));
                    c.IncludeXmlComments(
                        string.Format(
                            @"{0}\App_Data\SecurityApi.Core.xml",
                            System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory));
                })
                .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                    //for non-public sites, error widget will display 
                    //at bottom of swagger page unless disabled
                    c.DisableValidator()
                );
        }

        private static string GetRootUrlFromAppConfig()
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["swaggerBaseUrl"];
        }

        private static string GetSchemeFromAppConfig()
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["swaggerScheme"];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `SingleApiVersion` you need to use `MultipleApiVersions`

```
c.MultipleApiVersions(
    (apiDesc, targetApiVersion) => targetApiVersion.Equals("default", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ||                     // Include everything by default
                                    apiDesc.Route.RouteTemplate.StartsWith(targetApiVersion, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase), // Only include matching routes for other versions
    (vc) =>
    {
        vc.Version("default", "Swagger_Test");
        vc.Version("v1_0", "Swagger_Test V1_0");
        vc.Version("v2_0", "Swagger_Test V2_0");
    });
```

Look at the examples on the project page:
[Swashbuckle/blob/master/README.md#describing-multiple-api-versions](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/master/README.md#describing-multiple-api-versions)

There is also an example on the UnitTests:
[Swashbuckle/blob/master/Swashbuckle.Tests/Swagger/CoreTests.cs#L457](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/master/Swashbuckle.Tests/Swagger/CoreTests.cs#L457)